# Match statement spaced words return results from multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search, match

In this situation, I want to find all records that contain the name steve in one column and email@email.com in another. I know Im missing an operator, but i dont know which

```
            SELECT firstname,lastname,middlename,company_name, 
                    primary_emailaddress,alternate_emailaddress,personal_address_line1,
                    personal_address_line2,personal_address_city,facebook_username,
                    twitter_username,googleplus_username,linkedin_username,
                    personal_website_url,birthday_month,notes,personal_address_zipcode,
                    company_address_zipcode,home_phonenumber,company_phonenumber,
                    cell_phonenumber,birthday_day,birthday_year,hash,image_file
             FROM contacts
             WHERE (
                MATCH(
                    firstname,lastname,
                    primary_emailaddress,alternate_emailaddress,personal_address_line1,
                    personal_address_city,company_name,
                    company_address_line1,company_address_city,
                    facebook_username,twitter_username,googleplus_username,linkedin_username,
                    personal_website_url
                )
                AGAINST ('Steve email@email.com' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
```

Comment: Just to be sure: "steve" an "email@email.com" might appear in *any* column ?!? And is it required for the two values to appear in *different* columns?

Comment: no they can appear in the same column too

Comment: but "steve" and "email@email.com" might appear anywhere (like say, in column `personal_address_city`)?

Comment: if an email address can appear in the field for company_address_city, for example, you have data validation issues which need to be corrected much more urgently than figuring out this query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Match` is faster than a `like` comparison.  I think you can do it twice in a `where` clause:

```
        SELECT firstname,lastname,middlename,company_name, 
                primary_emailaddress,alternate_emailaddress,personal_address_line1,
                personal_address_line2,personal_address_city,facebook_username,
                twitter_username,googleplus_username,linkedin_username,
                personal_website_url,birthday_month,notes,personal_address_zipcode,
                company_address_zipcode,home_phonenumber,company_phonenumber,
                cell_phonenumber,birthday_day,birthday_year,hash,image_file
         FROM contacts
         WHERE MATCH (firstname) AGAINST ('Steve' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0 and
               MATCH (primary_emailaddress, alternate_emailaddress)
                     AGAINST ('email@email.com' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are really looking through every field, (i.e. John Stevenson would be considered a match on 'Steve') you can do this much simpler...

```
select *
from contacts

where firstname like '%Steve%'
 and (primary_emailaddress like '%email@email.com%' or alternate_emailaddress like '%email@email.com%')
```